# Would the Torah be the same if not for the primordial sin?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, adam

This question encompasses more information than my header had stated, but namely, I’m inquiring;

1. How would the Torah have been given if the sin had not occurred?
2. Would the Torah possess the same content as it does today? It is known the Torah existed prior to the creation of the world; thus perhaps in a world where the sin wasn’t committed, certain events would not occur (e.g. Cain would not kill Hebel because of immortality)

Comment: The specific formulation of the Torah as transmitted to Moshe was after all these events. The Torah as it existed in Heaven, prior to the creation of the world, had a less solidified form. It is written in Seforim Hakedoshim (I don't remember where) that the letters of the Torah, as it existed in Heaven, may be combined differently, forming different words.

Comment: @shmu It's worth to post your comment as an answer I think.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question but there are many answers to it, mine is only one of the existing approaches:

The Mishnah in Avos (3,15) states "הכל צפוי והרשות נתונה", meaning "Everything is foreseen". And it makes sense if we accept the axiom that the Torah not only preceded the creation of the world, but the creation actually follows what's written in it, as in Zohar Terumah

> **זוהר תרומה ח"ב קסא, א**:
>   דכד ברא קוב"ה עלמא אסתכל בה באורייתא וברא עלמא ובאורייתא אתברי עלמא."
>
> THat's how G-d created the word - He looked in the Torah and created the world, the world was created by the Torah.

Therefore, if the Torah tells us about the sin, it means it was destined to occur, even if we hold that "הרשות נתונה" - the [perception of] free will exists.

So everything that happened in the Jewish and human history was pretty much destined to happen.

Comment: Not disagreeing with this answer, just building on it: Sefer Nesivos Shalom (Slonim) often quotes a teaching of the Maggid of Kuzhnitz, who, commenting on the Maharal, posits that there are two parallel, co-existing tracks in world history. There is the regular track, by which certain sins and tragic events -- including the four exiles -- are pre-ordained, because this is the way that leads to the ultimate Redemption. But there is a parallel track that can override and preempt the ordained facts of history, and bring the Redemption at any moment. It is our choice which track to follow.

Comment: @shmu Personally I disagree with the second approach as it exists only in our perception. The reality of time in my view exists only in our brains as unable to perceive all at once. For G-d's perspective everything "exists" at once. Think about a movie file on your harddrive. You can't see it all at once, you see it frame by frame, and that gives you the feeling of the passage of time and causality - because A happened before B, A caused B. But in G-d's eyes the file is one, just a bunch of 1s and 0s.

Comment: When the Redemption comes, "az yimalei sechok pinu", as we recite in Shir HaMaalos. Harav Doniel Belsky shlita is fond of saying that in retrospect, we will view all the events of history with joy, even the tragic ones, because we will gain a new perspective on them, one that is closer to Hashem's perspective as you mentioned, in which the totality of time is viewed at once. Viewed in this way, things look very different.